# Symfony Forms and ManyToMany. How to configure form with file upload field that is also EntityType field?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms, entitymanager

I need to make form field with file upload that is also part of ManyToMany entity. Now my configuration looks like below, and it works...

```
class ProductTypeNew extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('price')
            ->add('description', TextareaType::class)
            ->add('quantity')
            ->add('file', FileType::class, array('label' => 'Zdjęcie'))
        ;
```

... but I need to manually get form input in controller and sets to form entity

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
{
    $image = new ShopProductImages();

    $file = $product->getFile();

    $fileName = $this->generateUniqueFileName().'.'.$file->guessExtension();

    $file->move(
        $this->getParameter('shop_images_directory'),
        $fileName
    );

    $image->setFile($fileName);
    $product->addShopProductImages($image);
    $product->setFile($fileName);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($image);
    $em->persist($product);
    $em->flush();
```

I would like to do something like this (but it's not working):

```
        ->add('shopProductImages', EntityType::class, array(
                'by_reference' => false,
                'entry_type' => FileType::class,
            )
```

---

New version of form types with Embeded Forms that also cause problem:

> Expected value of type "Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection|array"
>   for association field
>   "AppBundle\Entity\ShopProducts#$shopProductImages", got
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile" instead.

... with below configuration:

ProductTypeNew:

```
class ProductTypeNew extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', null, array('label' => 'Nazwa'))
            ->add('price', null, array('label' => 'Cena'))
            ->add('description', TextareaType::class, array('label' => 'Opis'))
            ->add('quantity', null, array('label' => 'Ilość'))
            ->add('shopProductImages', ShopProductsImagesType::class);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => ShopProducts::class,
        ]);
    }
```

ShopProductsImagesType:

```
class ShopProductsImagesType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('file', FileType::class, array('label' => 'Zdjęcie'))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
//            'data_class' => ShopProductImages::class,
            'data_class' => null,
        ]);
    }
```

Entity ShopProducts:

```
/**
 * ShopProducts
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="shop_products")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ShopProducts
{
   ....

    /**
     * INVERSE SIDE
     *
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(
     *     targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\ShopProductImages",
     *     mappedBy="shopProducts",
     *     cascade={"persist"}
     * )
     */
    private $shopProductImages;
```

Entity ShopProductImages:

```
* @ORM\Entity
 */
class ShopProductImages
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="file", type="text", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $file;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use EntityType field class, the `entry_type` is not an expected type. It expects to use an Entity binded to your database through Doctrine, from `yourbundleapp/Entity`. EntityType acts like a ChoiceType, but it directly interact with the Doctrine entity declared in parameter class. You can find how it works here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html

From what I can understand, you want to be able to download files on your app, so maybe you have difficulties to understand how submission forms work on Symfony.

You have to first define your new entity (from yourbundleapp/Entity), and then pass it as an argument to your form (from yourbundleapp/Form), like this:

`$image = new ShopProductImages();
$form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(ProductTypeNew::class, $image);`

If you want, you can also add form in your first form by embedding it: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/embedded.html

If I understood bad, please could you be more verbose about what you want to do and what you did?

Comment: Thanks, for help, I updated main post with implementation of  form embeded but got new error.